# Code in browser isn't working in Dreamweaver CC

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I've got the following HTML and CSS code:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>

.button {
    width: 239px;
    height: 59px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    background-color: #D1BF92;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    }
</style>

</head>
<a href="#" class="button"></a>
</html>
```

When I open this up in any browser (Chrome, firefox, ie) I get a **"Rotated"** rectangular box.

However in dreamweaver I get a horizontal rectangular box. Any Ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you see in Dreamweaver doesn't necessarily reflect the final product as it likely uses a different rendering engine. Therefore, stop worrying about what you see in Dreamweaver and start checking it in your browser. Your end users won't be viewing your website with Dreamweaver will they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because it is possible that Dreamweaver doesn't support the transform property. It is always better to view it in a real browser rather than a WYSIWYG editor, because the browser is what the user is going to view your webpage in.